# heroku mysql2 problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting this error when i type

```
@entries = Entry.all
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
>   (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"entries"' at line 1: SELECT
>   `entries`.* FROM "entries"):

my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.8'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "mysql2", "0.2.6"
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: heroku ain't working with sql. Do you use RDS or Xeround?

Comment: i'm trying to establish connection to my mysql server. it works fine in local.

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate to get your database table out there?

Answer (score -2):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL, so I guess your problem is the mysql2 gem. You need to use the pg gem with Heroku. It's a good idea to use Postgres locally to avoid incompatibility issues.

However, if you really want to use MySQL locally, then you could try to change your Gemfile to use the mysql2 gem locally and use the pg gem in production:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Comment: Heroku supports Mysql using clearDB as addon. The answer doesn't make sense.